# C++: Debug assertion failed, afx.inl line 122

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

here is the description of the problem.

I have the following class defined..

```
class classA {
public:
  CString aString;
};
extern classA theApp;
```

in another class function, I do this

```
theApp.aString = "test string";
```

then I get the runtime error debug assertion failed, afx.inl line 122;
please advise.

I tried to do the allocation inside the class as well but it fails flagging the same runtime error.

```
 class classA {
    public:
      CString aString;
      void set_string()
      {
          aString = "test string 2";
      }
    };
    extern classA theApp;

    //in another class function

    theApp.set_string();
```

visual c++ version: VC++ 6.0

Comment: Is the assignment to `aString` done while another global variable is being constructed (i.e., before theApp has been constructed)?  If so you can be accessing `theApp.aString` before `theApp` has been constructed.

Comment: Would be quite helpful to know the full error message.  You can click retry in the debugger and then walk up the stack to where the assert is and you should see the full message.  If you're already running in the debugger it should be in the output window.

Answer (score 1):

> afx.inl` line 122:
>   ASSERT(m_pchData != NULL); return ((CStringData*)m_pchData)-1; }

It seems, that your `theApp` variable is not initialized properly, since its members `aString` internal buffer is `NULL`, check that you are not making an assignment before its initialization.

Also ensure that you have the latest service pack (SP6) installed for the Visual Studio 6.

Comment: i set a function inside classA function

Comment: `i set a function inside classA function` This needs clarifying since it doesn't make sense as written. You are calling a member function of `classA` but if that call is made from the constructor or initializer of another global variable, then it *is* possible that `theApp` may have not been constructed at that point, yet (as the answer above and a previous comment suggest).